# ThreeJS and PhysiJS "Class constructor cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, physijs

I'm trying to implement PhysiJS to my ThreeJS project.

**To simplify I have downloaded this project from the web:**
https://rawgit.com/mmmovania/Physijs_Tutorials/master/MultipleBoxes.html

**My project setup is available here:**
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lO-8YQtWkOPDhsEpk1LzuPajoPjsBnyo?usp=sharing

**Problem**
When I have downloaded all the files (html, js) I tried to run it.
When it's run from my computer I receive an error.

I'm still very new to JavaScript I kind of understand what the problem is but not sure how to solve it. What am I missing? It's the exact same project on my PC as it is on the web.

Here's the error:

```
**three.js:34977 THREE.Quaternion: .inverse() has been renamed to invert().

Quaternion.inverse @ three.js:34977
physi.js:391 Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Scene cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at new window.Physijs.Physijs.Scene (physi.js:391)
    at init (MultipleBoxes.html:71)
    at MultipleBoxes.html:51**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `init()` to `window.onload = init();` to give the script files a chance to load completely before you init().

```js
'use strict';


var initScene, render, renderer, scene, camera, box, floor;
var container;
var camera, scene, controls, renderer;
var mouseX = 0,
  mouseY = 0;
var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
var clock;

var NUM_BOXES = 10;

// always wait for all scripts to load before doing assignments
window.onload = function() {
  init();
  animate();
}



function init() {


  // initialize your script and set assignments
  Physijs.scripts.worker = 'js/physijs_worker.js';
  Physijs.scripts.ammo = 'ammo.js';

  clock = new THREE.Clock();


  container = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(container);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000);

  camera.position.z = 20;
  camera.position.y = 5;

  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);


  // scene

  //scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene = new Physijs.Scene;
  scene.setGravity(new THREE.Vector3(0, -10, 0));

  //floor
  floor = new Physijs.BoxMesh(
    new THREE.CubeGeometry(20, 0.1, 20),
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color: 0xffffff
    }),
    0 //mass
  );
  floor.receiveShadow = true;
  floor.position.set(0, 0, 0);
  scene.add(floor);


  var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader(manager);
  var crateTexture = new THREE.Texture();

  loader.load('textures/crate.jpg', function(image) {
    crateTexture.image = image;
    crateTexture.needsUpdate = true;
  });

  // Box
  var boxGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1, 1, 1);
  var boxMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff,
    map: crateTexture
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < NUM_BOXES; ++i) {
    var box = new Physijs.BoxMesh(boxGeometry, boxMaterial);
    box.castShadow = true;
    box.position.y = 10 + 2 * i;
    scene.add(box);
  }


  var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
  manager.onProgress = function(item, loaded, total) {
    console.log(item, loaded, total);
  };


  var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x707070);
  scene.add(ambientLight);

  var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
  light.position.set(-10, 18, 5);
  light.castShadow = true;
  var d = 14;
  light.shadow.camera.left = -d;
  light.shadow.camera.right = d;
  light.shadow.camera.top = d;
  light.shadow.camera.bottom = -d;

  light.shadow.camera.near = 2;
  light.shadow.camera.far = 50;

  light.shadow.mapSize.x = 1024;
  light.shadow.mapSize.y = 1024;

  scene.add(light);

  //

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

}

function onWindowResize() {

  windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
  windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

}

function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {

  mouseX = (event.clientX - windowHalfX) / 2;
  mouseY = (event.clientY - windowHalfY) / 2;

}

//

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();

}

function render() {
  var deltaTime = clock.getDelta();
  controls.update(deltaTime);
  scene.simulate(); // run physics

  camera.lookAt(scene.position);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Monospace;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#info {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 100;
  display: block;
}

#info a,
.button {
  color: #f00;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Physijs + THREE.js = Multiple Boxes Demo</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    /* moved to separate box for stackoverflow answer 
   (see CSS box)
  */
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <script src="js/three.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/physi.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

  <script>
    /* moved to javascript box */
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Great, I will try this as soon as I get the chance. Thank you so much @mike510a! 

Comment: Thaank you it worked @mike510a !

Comment: Great! don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the little green check box to  the left of the answer (this is so that this question will not be listed as unanswered)

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of the check mark!